# jquery: create multiple elements in one line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following example in which I'm adding nested elements to the DOM:

```js
$ul = $('<ul>').appendTo($('#test'));
$('<li>').text('Item 1').appendTo($ul);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Is there anyway I can write the two javascript lines in one line. I've tried the following to no avail:

```
$('<li>').text('Item 1').appendTo($('<ul>')).appendTo($('#test'))
```

Notice the `<ul>` element does NOT get added: https://jsfiddle.net/upnchucq/

Comment: `$('#test').append($('<ul>').append($('<li>').text('Item 1')));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misplaced one parentheses.

The code should look like:

```
$('<li>').text('Item 1').appendTo($('<ul>').appendTo($('#test')));
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/upnchucq/2/